# Assigning a color to the text is not working in tailwindcss

Tags: php, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to apply color to a text using tailwindcss but it's not working.

Here is the code-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="text-yellow-400 font-bold">
            Hello, world!
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what that looks like in the browser. It seems like the class is not being applied.

[image]

Comment: Does your output.css include `.text-yellow-400`? Tailwind typically needs some sort of bundler that only includes the classes that you need. Of course you could have included the entire tailwind set, but that would be somewhat wasteful for a production build.

Comment: I tried the code in codepen, can't see any issue. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Tailwind with the CDN because maybe `output.css` doesn't contain the feature you want to use.

````
```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="text-yellow-400 font-bold">
            Hello world!
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please add the reason why this solves the problem?